# PowerPivot data feed error "Semicolon expected" during import

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, xml, atom-feed, powerpivot

When importing data from an atom feed in PowerPivot, I get the following error:

> XML parsing failed at line 7, column 727: Semicolon expected.

The feed currently only returns two entries, and PowerPivot's "Preview & Filter" feature has no problems displaying these entries. However, when attempting to import the rows, PowerPivot reports the error above.

I am using the latest version of PowerPivot for Excel 2010.

**What could be causing this error?**

Other information:

- I tried saving the raw XML from the feed to a file - **PowerPivot reads *this* "feed" just fine!**
- Basic authentication (user/password) is required to access the feed.
- I suspected it might have to do with my locale settings (Denmark), but changing these to United States had no effect.
- I have validated the raw feed contents using the [Atom Feed Validator](http://validator.w3.org/appc/#validate_by_input), and it comes out valid.
- I tried locating the position to which the error refers, but the whole XML feed is returned without insignificant white space, i.e. as a single line. Where is line 7 then?

All of the above makes me think that this has nothing to do with the feed itself, but how PowerPivot handles the feed.

---

**Update:** This error doesn't occur on our client's computer, thus confirming that the problem lies within PowerPivot and not the feed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem loading a Microsoft SQL Azure Database into excel. The way I got past this was connecting via powerquery and selecting all the tables. This automatically creates the data model in powerpivot for me to use. I know this was posted over a year ago, hope this helps someone else looking for answers to this.